# creating cutout from fill with text in actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm building a site in actionscript 3. I created a grid with Squares where the text is cut out so the background can be shown through. Right now I'm doing this by loading in hundreds of png's in via XML, but this causes a significant increase in size of the site.

I was wondering if it was possible to cutout the text like you would normally do in flash by breaking apart the text and then converting them to fills so they can be removed from the fill. I am now looking for a way to do this in actionscript, to save space and time.
I have researched the subject and I havent found any info on how to do this in actionscript.

In short:

I want to create a fill where the text is cut out in actionscript 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Here is a way to do that using a dynamic text field as a mask. The trick is to invert the alpha channel of the text field. 
This class creates a color bitmapData with transparency. 
Then it creates a text field.
Then it creates a bitmapData to draw the text field in. 
It draws the text, then reverses the alpha channel of the text, so that it will cut out what was previously shown. 
We apply the alpha channel of the text bitmapdata to the color bitmapdat, so that the color will have the text cut out of it.
Finally. we add a Bitmap to show our work. (so you can see that the colro has the text cut out of it.) 
If you run this on your machine it will look kind of jaggy because it will use he default font with no anit-aliasing. But you could easily create your own text field with a custom font and draw that instead. Then it will look smooth.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.BitmapDataChannel;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TextEvent;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Zachary Foley
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            // Make a red square bitmapdata that allows transparency.
            var color:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 400, true, 0xFF990000);
            var word:TextField = new TextField;
            word.text = "HELLO MASK";
            var textMask:BitmapData = new BitmapData(word.width, word.height, true, 0x00000000);
            textMask.draw(word);
            textMask = invert(textMask);

            var colorHolder:Bitmap = new Bitmap(color);
            addChild(colorHolder);
            color.copyChannel(textMask, textMask.rect, new Point(0, 0), BitmapDataChannel.RED, BitmapDataChannel.ALPHA);
        }

        private function invert(oldBmp:BitmapData):BitmapData {
            var source:BitmapData = oldBmp;
            var destination_bitmap:BitmapData = source.clone();
            var rectan:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, source.width, source.height);

            // Replace all transparent pixels with a solid color
            destination_bitmap.threshold(source, rectan, new Point(), "==", 0x00000000,0xFFFF0000);
            // Replace all the pixels greater than 0xf1f1f1 by transparent pixels
            destination_bitmap.threshold(source, rectan, new Point(), "==", 0xff656565,0x0000FF00);          
            return destination_bitmap;
        }

    }

}
```